# Using sklearn.neural_network version 0.18.dev0 Simulatenously With scikit-learn 0.17

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network

I'm using two versions of scikits-learn, for different purposes:

- scikits-learn 0.17 for production
- scikits-learn 0.18, specifically its [neural network library](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html), for education purposes

Note that at the time of writing this:

- scikits-learn 0.18 is still in development.
- scikits-learn 0.17 does not have a neural network library.

Until 0.18 becomes stable, I'd like to use, in production, 0.18 for neural networks, and 0.17 for anything else, from within the same code. Is there a way of installing two such version simultaneously so that they are both callable from within the same code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not the exact answer I was looking for it did solve my problem.

I was after two things:

1. Using Sklearn 0.17 in my production code.
   `
2. Using a strong neural network library that can work with it.

My initial attempts where:

1. SKNN - which fits the Sklearn API, but is not maintained and has migrated into Sklearn 0.18 as sklearn.neural_network
2. Using Sklearn 0.18's neural_network along side Sklearn 0.17 (which was the origin for my question)

The solution I found was using [TensorFlow.contrib.learn](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn), also referred to as [SKFlow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/skflow).

SKFlow is what I was looking for:

1. A strong and highly maintained neural network library (adopted into TensorFlow as a module a few months ago)
2. Fully compatible with Sklearn 0.17's API.